# Cannot redeclare date_diff() in PHP 5.3.28

Tags: php

I've read that this function should work in 5.3 but not 5.2 so I am unsure why I am getting fatal errors from PHP.  Sadly I am not a coder by any means, was hoping I could get some guidance.  Thanks!

```
function date_diff($start, $end="NOW")
{
    $sdate = strtotime($start);
    $edate = strtotime($end);

    $time = $edate - $sdate;
    if($time>=86400) {
        // Days + Hours + Minutes
        $pday = ($edate - $sdate) / 86400;
        $preday = explode('.',$pday);

        $phour = $pday-$preday[0];
        $prehour = explode('.',$phour*24);

        $premin = ($phour*24)-$prehour[0];
        $min = explode('.',$premin*60);

        $presec = '0.'.$min[1];
        $sec = $presec*60;

        $timeshift = $preday[0];
    }else{
            $timeshift = 0;
    }
    return $timeshift;
}
```

Comment: [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) is already a php function for php5.3>.

Comment: Either someone has defined it already or you are not using PHP < 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot redeclare XXXX() simply means that you are trying to declare somethign that already exists.

The date_diff function has already been defined so check if it is already defined before defining it again. You can do this using [function_exists()](http://us.php.net/function_exists)

```
if (!function_exists("date_diff"))
{
  function date_diff($start, $end="NOW")
  {
                $sdate = strtotime($start);
                $edate = strtotime($end);

                $time = $edate - $sdate;
                if($time>=86400) {
                                // Days + Hours + Minutes
                                $pday = ($edate - $sdate) / 86400;
                                $preday = explode('.',$pday);

                                $phour = $pday-$preday[0];
                                $prehour = explode('.',$phour*24);

                                $premin = ($phour*24)-$prehour[0];
                                $min = explode('.',$premin*60);

                                $presec = '0.'.$min[1];
                                $sec = $presec*60;

                                $timeshift = $preday[0];

                }else{
                        $timeshift = 0;
                }
                return $timeshift;
  }
}
```

Just to clarify, you only need to define the function like this is you want your code to work on versions of php newer **AND** older than 5.3 If you are only using 5.3+ then you do not need to declare this function at all as it already exists, you can just use date_diff() without defining it